Not Redirecting to the Web page
I'm trying to create a login system in PHP with JavaScript that redirects users to different pages based on their role (student, tutor, admin). The login process seems to work, but the page redirection isn't happening correctly. Can someone help me identify what I'm doing wrong?
The login process seems to work, but the page redirection isn't happening correctly. Even if the login is successful and the correct role is returned, the user isn't redirected to the correct page (e.g., student.php).
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Register</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/form.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="form">
        <h2>Login Form</h2>
        <form action="" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="error-text">Error</div>

            <div class="input">
                <label>NIC</label>
                <input type="nic" name="nic" placeholder="Enter Your NIC" required>
            </div>

            <div class="input">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Your Password" required>
            </div>

            <div class="submit">
                <input type="submit" value="Login Now" class="button">
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="link">Not signup ? <a href="register.php">SignUp Now</a> </div>


    </div>

    <script>src="js/login.js"</script>


</body>

</html>

const form = document.querySelector('.form form');
const submitbtn = form.querySelector('.submit input');
const errortxt = form.querySelector('.error-text');

form.onsubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
};

submitbtn.onclick = () => {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "php/login.php", true);
    xhr.onload = () => {
        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                let data = xhr.response.trim();
                console.log("Response:", data); // Log the response for debugging
                if (data === "student") {
                    location.href = "student.php";
                } else if (data === "tutor") {
                    location.href = "tutor.php";
                } else if (data === "admin") {
                    location.href = "admin.php";
                } else {
                    errortxt.textContent = data;
                    errortxt.style.display = "block";  
                }
            }
        }
    };

    let formData = new FormData(form);
    xhr.send(formData);
};


<?php
session_start();
include 'db.php';

$nic = $_POST['nic'];
$password = md5($_POST["password"]);

if (!empty($nic) && !empty($password)) {
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM user_reg WHERE nic ='{$nic}' AND password = '{$password}'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
        if ($row) {
            $_SESSION['nic'] = $row['nic'];
            $_SESSION['password'] = $row['password'];
            $role = $row['role']; // Ensure 'role' column exists and has the correct value
            echo $role; // Return the role instead of a success message
        }
    } else {
        echo "NIC or Password is Incorrect";
    }
} else {
    echo "All Fields are required";
}
?>



Why use AJAX if you redirect anyway? Just redirect from the server. Also if you insist, I strongly suggest you change to form.addEventListener('submit',  (e) => {     e.preventDefault();   let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); ... }); instead of using the submit button click event

From PHP's md5 manual: "Warning It is not recommended to use this function to secure passwords, due to the fast nature of this hashing algorithm. See the Password Hashing FAQ for details and best practices."

"redirection isn't happening correctly" - Please explain what actually happens. No redirection? Page reload? Redirecting to the wrong URL in your if-statement? Redirecting to some other page not in the code?

Sidenote: There should be no reason to store the users password (hashed or not) in the session.

Without the proper description of what the code is doing and what you want it to do, it is hard to say, but I think you need to redirect to "/student.php" or "/tutor.php" instead of redirecting to "student.php" and "tutor.php"
